# Rendering arrays attached to Models inside a Collection - mixin?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

Let's say I have a model, and it has an array of items associated with it.

```
class window.MyModel extends Backbone.Model

  urlRoot: () ->
    '/model/' + @attributes.name

  defaults:
    name: null
    items: []

  initialize: () ->
    @name = @attributes.name
    @items = @attributes.items

  parse: (resp) ->
    # Example build resp
    @items.push '1'
    @items.push '2'

    @attributes.items = @items

    @
```

And a collection, which holds all the models. Fetching the collection just returns a list of model names, nothing detailed about them (hence the inner fetch).

```
class window.MyCollection extends Backbone.Collection

  url: '/collection'
  model: window.MyModel

  fetch: (options) ->
    # IE cache
    Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call @, options

  parse: (resp) ->

    myModels = []

    # Example build resp
    myModel1 = new window.MyModel(name: 'myModel1')
    myModel1.fetch()

    myModel2 = new window.MyModel(name: 'myModel2')
    myModel2.fetch()

    myModels.push myModel1
    myModels.push myModel2

    myModels
```

What is the best way to build a CompositeView from the `items` array after a fetch is made without getting wonky? A mixin, perhaps?

Fetch the collection, add it to a view:

```
myColl = new MyCollection()
myColl.fetch()

# which looks like: [{"name":"myModel1",items:["1","2"]},{"name":"myModel2",items:["1","2"]}]

someLayout.region.show new MyCollectionOfItemsViewThatIsAMarionetteCompositeView(
  collection: myColl # But really, I just want a collection of all the items (unique) that are in the models
)
```

Essentially, if the CompositeView were to normally render with a template like:

```
<% obj.name %>
```

You'd have `myModel1` and `myModel2` as page elements.

But I want `1` and `2` (in this example case) to be rendered as page elements. Maybe with a template like below:

```
<% obj.item %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you an array of unique items from the collection's models:

```
_.uniq(_.union(myColl.pluck("items")))
```

You should be able to figure out how to use that call to get what you want.